# Excel Function - Set Cell Color based on Another Cell Selection

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need to write a function to color a bunch of cells in one row based on the colors of cells in another row. I've tried some different VBA variations, but this is what I am wanting to do:

```
Public Function CopyColorFormat(Target As Range)

    If Not Target.Interior.Color Is Nothing Then

        ActiveCell.Interior.ThemeColor = Target.Interior.ThemeColor

    End If

End Function
```

I then went to A1 and set the formula to =CopyColorFormat(C1). (C1 is Purple and I want A1 to also be shaded Purple.) However, this results in a #VALUE! error in the cell I try to put the function in.

The reason I am wanting this and not to use conditional formatting is that I need to apply this to a *ton* of cells (via their corresponding cell) and dont want to make a rule for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about functions, but this macro should do the trick for you.

```
Sub color_cells()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentcell As Range
Dim copycell As Range
Dim current As Long
Dim copy As Long

Set currentcell = Range("A1")
Set copycell = Range("C1")
current = 1
copy = 1

For x = 1 To 8 ' instead of 8 - enter the number of rows you want the code to run on.
    If Not copycell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then

    copycell.copy
    currentcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End If

    current = current + 1
    copy = copy + 1

    Set currentcell = Range("A" & current)
    Set copycell = Range("C" & copy)
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You might want to specify which workbook and worksheet the code runs on if you work with multiple at the same time.

Comment: Hi JoeBerg! I think that is going to work well!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help :)